# Pinging Google Analytics API v4 every few seconds shows fluctuations in total sessions

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm pinging the Google Analytics API v4 every 3 seconds and grabbing the total sessions of 4 metro areas between the a single starting date and up to today.

```
dateRanges: [{
    startDate: '2019-08-14',
    endDate: 'today'
}],
metrics: [{
    expression: 'ga:sessions'
}],
dimensions: [{
    "name": "ga:metro"
}],
```

However, the reports that come back fluctuate up and down in total sessions, which is strange because total sessions shouldn't be able to go down.

I've attached a screenshot of the console.log output of total sessions reported back from the API every 3 seconds:

[image]

Is the reporting inaccurate when including the current day or am I retrieving data incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processing latency for Google Analytics data  is 24-48 hours so there's no hope for getting accurate today's session numbers https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=en#DataProcessingLatency
Beside, pinging Reporting API every 3 seconds might deplete your API quota and that's not an intended use.

Comment: That's what I figured. The 3 seconds ping was just for testing the variability in the report's total sessions and not what's going to production. Thanks for the link!

Comment: GA provides specific parameter that indicates finalized data, this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48024517/ga-api-confirmation-to-get-full-day-of-data/48034901#48034901

Comment: Thank you - I might use that in the future but for this particular project I'll need to display the current day's evolving data, even if it's slightly inaccurate.